# HTML 5 (Bootstrap) run animation by function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have Bootstrap dashboard widget animation, i want recall the animation by javascript function

```
<div id="mywidget" class="xe-widget xe-counter xe-counter-purple" data-count=".num" data-from="1" data-to="2101" data-suffix=" Word" data-duration="3" data-easing="false"
```

i was tried using this function and still dont work

```
function callagaintheanimation() {
            $("#mywidget").attr( "data-count",".num" );
            $("#mywidget").attr( "data-from","0" );
            $("#mywidget").attr( "data-to","2101" );
            $("#mywidget").attr( "data-suffix"," Word" );
            $("#mywidget").attr( "data-duration","2" );
            $("#mywidget").attr( "class","xe-widget xe-counter xe-counter-purple" );        
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

i was found the answer... i need re init again the widget...

with call

```
setupWidgets();
```

inside the function is :

```
var setupWidgets = function()
    {       
        // Count Anything
        $("[data-from][data-to]").each(function(i, el)
...
```